# not show error list in ejs tample in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i using the nodejs . i have a form for register .

this is my js code :

```
Register(req, res) {
    res.render('auth/register', { messages: req.flash('errors') })
}

RegisterProcess(req, res) {

    var validateResult = validationResult(req);

    if (!validateResult.isEmpty()) {
        const errors = validateResult.array();
        let messages = [];
        errors.forEach(error => {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        req.flash('errors', messages)
        res.redirect('/auth/register');

    }
}
```

and this is the `ejs` file :

```
 <% if(messages.length > 0) { %>
    <ul>
      <% messages.forEach(err=>{ %>
        <li><%- err %></li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
    <% } %>
```

but it not show me any error .

i `log` the `messages` in the `RegisterProcess` and it return the errors in console but when i `log` in the `Register` it not show me any error in the console.

i console this in the Register Controller `req.flash('errors')` but it just show me the empty array `[]` .

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

change this  `<li><%- err %></li>`

to `<li><%= - err %></li>`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.